# Hadoop Cannot connect to the Map/Reduce location: localhost

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to create a new DFSLocation but I could't able to connect

Below is the error message . Please someone suggest me.

"Cannot connect to the Map/Reduce location: localhost
Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information"

Comment: Problem is solved:
Delete the Map/Reduce Locations in the eclipse.
Close Map/Reduce from right top corner in the eclipse.
Delete the tmp folder created

Comment: Run commands for namenaoe, secondarynamenode,jobtracker,datanode and tasktracker
in a separate cygwin command prompt. then create new Map/Reduce Location in eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

hi friends Rahul Tyagi here, i was having the same issue.

`$ vim /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml`

Open the terminal and paste the given address. Property folder will be open, then add:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
    <description>
       The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
       scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  
       The uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) 
       naming the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's
       authority is used to determine the host, port, etc.
       for a filesystem.
    </description>
</property>
```

Now 2nd step:

`$ vim /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:54311</value>
    <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
            at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
            and reduce task.
    </description>
</property>
```

That's all.